# How to add some HTML to the keywords that match as well as don't match a string

Tags: php, html

I have the code below which add a green tick next to the keywords in the variable $keywords if there are found in the variable $text, so Microsoft and Intel. Now this works fine, but I'd like also to add a red tick next to the keywords that doesn't match the keywords in $text i.e Nokia. So the desired output should be a green tick next to Microsoft and Intel and a red tick next to Nokia.

```
<?php

$text = array("microsoft","intel","nokia");
$keywords = array("microsoft","intel");

foreach ($text as $str) {

  foreach ($keywords as $keyword)

     $str = preg_replace("~(?<!\w)".preg_quote($keyword, "/")."\$~i", "<i class='fa fa-check-circle' style='font-size:15px;color:green'></i> $0</span>", $str);

     $string[] = $str;

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php

foreach ($string as $strings) {

echo $strings.'<br>';

}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use regular expressions for this task.

Instead make your keywords the keys of an array (instead of values), so you can do faster lookup, and then just check if the string is in that array (as key). If so, set a color variable to green, otherwise to red. Then add the corresponding tick symbol to the word:

```
$text = array("microsoft","intel","nokia");
$keywords = array_flip(array("microsoft","intel"));

foreach ($text as $str) {
    $color = isset($keywords[$str]) ? "green" : "red";
    $string[] = "<i class='fa fa-check-circle' style='font-size:15px;color:$color'></i> $str";
}

foreach ($string as $strings) {
    echo "$strings<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your script a little, you don't need regex here, you can just check if needed string is in array of your keywords:

```
$text = array("microsoft","intel","nokia");
$keywords = array("microsoft","intel");

foreach ($text as $str) {
    $color = in_array($str, $keywords) ? 'green' : 'red';
    $string[] = sprintf("<i class='fa fa-check-circle' style='font-size:15px;color:%s'></i> %s</span>", $color, $str);
}
```

Comment: You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @JohnConde Sorry, added explanation

Comment: Thanks for your answer, much appreciated. But this is part of a bigger code, and it needs regex.